# How can I read a secure XML URI in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, https

I am trying to read a secure XML document from a URI in C#.  I understand the basics of the XmlReader class.  However I cannot figure out how to supply a username and password for the URI in code.  I get the feeling it has something to do with an XmlSecureResolver object.  But I can't figure out how to set the username and password.  Can anyone help me with how to set the credentials?

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usernamne", "password");

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) 
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        // Blah blah...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google of the term "XmlReader Authenticate" yields this as the first result:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47as68k4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

> When resolving a URL to a file that contains the XML data to read, the file may have a restricted access policy. If authentication is required to access a network resource, use the XmlResolver.Credentials property to specify the necessary credentials. If the XmlResolver.Credentials property is not set, then credentials are set to null.

```
XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader("http://localhost/bookstore/books.xml");
rdr.XmlResolver.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(rdr)
```

and using different credentials:

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(UserName, SecurelyStoredPassword, domain); 
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache(); 
myCache.Add(new Uri("www.contoso.com"), "Basic", myCred); 
myCache.Add(new Uri("app.contoso.com"), "Basic", myCred);
reader.XmlResolver.Credentials = myCache;
```